# How to import a virtual machine to VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, centos, virtualization

I have VirtualBox, and someone gave me a folder containing the following files:

- cOS.vbox
- cOS.vbox-prev
- cOS.vdi
- Logs

I want to use this with VirtualBox, but I'm not sure how.

I had created a virtual machine before for Ubuntu. From what I've seen, a folder for it was created in "VirtualBox VMs" folder in my user directory. I had thought that maybe copying the files above to this folder, cOS would appear listed in VirtualBox, but it doesn't. I'm on Mac OSX.

Comment: None of those files are the actual virtual machine. It will be much easier to just duplicate the virtual machine on the Hbuntu host with the same settings as the original host then use the same vhdd.

Comment: It's been asked before: http://superuser.com/questions/187598/how-to-open-existing-vms-in-virtualbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you not rather export it as an appliance on the source machine, as this will generate an additional file (.ovf) with XML content for ease of transfer

```
File > Export Appliance
```

And import it on the destination

```
File > Import Appliance
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Once you have copied the files in vitualbox VM folder, just double click on the cOS.vbox file, it will open the VM in virtual box.

Did this a long time ago on windows, should work on Mac as well.