# Oracle VBox inaccessible after change of name of user folder on Windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

Yesterday I changed name of my user file and name of account from "Król" to "Sotel" on Windows 10. Now my oracle vbox is inaccessible and shows error:

**Runtime error opening 'C:\Users\Kr�l\VirtualBox VMs\SW\SW.vbox' for reading: -103 (Path not found.).**

**F:\tinderbox\win-6.1\src\VBox\Main\src-server\MachineImpl.cpp[754] (long __cdecl Machine::i_registeredInit(void)).**

**Score number (RC): E_FAIL (0x80004005)**

**Component: MachineWrap Interface: IMachine {85632c68-b5bb-4316-a900-5eb28d3413df}**

I have already changed path to "C:\Users\Sotel\VirtualBox VMs" from "C:\Users\Król\VirtualBox VMs" in tab "general" in global settings of oracle virtual machine but it doesn't solve the issue. What should I do to make my vbox accessible again?

Comment: Remove and add it again? https://superuser.com/a/697206/554702

Comment: I don't want data of VBox to get lost.

Comment: You won't though?

Comment: So i deleted it and just turned it on again from the VBox machine folder and everything works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to remove the VM from the list of VMs (that reference the incorrect location) within VirtualBox and add the VM in it's new location.

Comment: Is that your answer: delete the VM?

Comment: @harrymc - The author's solution was to remove the VM from the list of VMs (that reference the incorrect location) within VirtualBox and add the VM in it's new location.

Comment: @Ramhound: Your explanation is better than the answer.

Comment: @harrymc - The author can certainly edit their answer to clarify it.  However, I honestly wouldn't answer a question like this normally, so I don't plan on trying to fix the answer myself.